# Input value doesn't hold the value after clicking button

Tags: laravel, input, printing

I'm trying to type invoice number as input type i.e. 123456789

[image]

After I click Print Record button, the value of invoice number disappears like this:

[image]

Aslo I have wrote

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="invoice_no" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Inovice Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-4" name="InvNumber" id="InvNumber" value="{{request()->input('InvNumber')}}">
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the Print button looks like:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 dol-12" >
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right" onclick="printDiv()">Print Record</button>
           </div>
```

And printDiv() function is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

                            function printDiv(divName) {

                                    var printContents = document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML;
                                    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

                                    window.print();
                                    }
```

Comment: What is written in `printDiv` function?

Comment: I edited my question, so you can look the edit above

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a submit button will submit the form it is in.

Presumably, your form's action is the current URL, so it reloads the page.

The new page doesn't have the data in the form fields that you had typed into the previous page.

If you don't want to submit the form, use the `type` attribute to change the `<button>` from its default of `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documenation, if you don't specify `type` of button it assumes it as `submit` button that is why your form is being submitted by default.

Add `type="button"` in your button

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" onclick="printDiv()">Print Record</button>
```

> **submit**: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the
>   default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with
>   a form**, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: can you pls share your complete form?

Comment: Can I write you privately, because I don't want to exaggerate the question for others

Comment: Im so confused in case of vatNumber, because it is OK also after clicking Print button, but invoice number not :/